# ActiveRecord before-transaction callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Problem**: I'm looking for an ActiveRecord (Rails 3.2) callback hook that will execute BEFORE a DB transaction has begun.

If it doesn't exist (and I don't think it does), then I'm looking for any advice in monkey-patching ActiveRecord so that we can implement such a method ourselves.

**What I've Tried**

Having looked at ActiveRecord docs and playing around with the code, it seems that only 'after_commit' is guaranteed to be executed outside a transaction.  Everything else ("before_validation", "before_save", "before_commit") is ran within the transaction. I've tried overriding the 'transaction' method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  included do |base|
    base.instance_eval do
    def before_transaction
      ### DO STUFF
    end

    def transaction(options = {}, &block)
       before_transaction { super(options, &block) }
    end
  end
end
```

But this is complicated because transaction is a class method and the callback has to be registered per instance of the model.  On top of that, it isn't guaranteed to run outside of a DB transaction because it could be nested:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    user.update_attribute(name: "Hodor")
  end
end
```

Not sure what I want is possible given the way ActiveRecord is implemented, because it may not be possible to know if another transaction has already begun and invoke the callback then. In any case, I thought it's worth asking here.

**Background**

I'm trying to 'sync' an existing Rails model (let's call it User) to a user service that lives elswhere. The user service should act as the source of truth.

Whenever updates happen to the Rails User model, I would like to validate + commit the change to the user service first, before saving to the DB (which only the Rails project use). The DB for the Rails project then functions as a write-through cache (why a Database for a cache? Legacy code reasons).

If we could call the service BEFORE writing to the DB, we don't have to worry about rolling back the transaction (and dealing with what happens when that rolling back fails!). However, I am hesitant to call the service in the middle of an open DB transaction, which is why I'm looking into whether or not it's possible to build a "before_transaction" callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a service object which handles all of this functionality?

```
class UserService
  attr_accessor :user

  def initialize(user, params)
    @user = user
    @params = params
  end

  def save
    external_result = API.call_to_external

    if external_result
      @user.update(@params)
    end
  end
end

user_service = UserService.new(user, params)
user_service.save
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- it's a good idea. My only concern is that it's a level higher than the model itself, and we might miss places where the user object is being modified directly -- for example, relations between models in Rails will continue to work without using this new UserService object.

Comment: Fair point. If your external service is your source of truth though, I don't see a scenario in which you should be relying on rails relationships (callbacks, nested attributes, etc) anyway. Seems as if every call to update should be hitting this external service first. You should never be calling a .update directly?

Comment: I agree, I just think it's a bit tricky to track down all the direct calls to .update because those calls can be quite implicit (relations being one such example). I suppose over-riding "save" and "update" and other methods to throw an error might be a good way to track them down, though.